# How to calculate the differential scattering cross section?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, nanoscience, scattering-cross-section

I am doing some simulations with the [Meep code](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep) to study some properties of a metal nanoparticle.

The situation is this: an incident electromagnetic wave on a metal nanoparticle. By now I know how to calculate the scattering, absorption and extinction cross sections and their efficiencies but I need the scattering angular distribution, that's why I need to calculate the differential scattering cross section and now I am a bit lost.

Is there a way to relate the cross section to the differential cross section?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically what you're looking for, but I can give you the basic idea of the relation between the cross section and the *differential* cross section. Generally, the cross section $\sigma$ is defined as the integral of the differential cross section $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$ over the entire solid angle. Here, $d\Omega$ is the spherical surface element: $d\Omega\equiv \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi $, with $\theta$ and $\phi$ the usual angles defined on the sphere, which parametrize the outgoing direction of the scattering object. So, we have 
$$\sigma=\oint d\Omega \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} $$ In many cases, we have cylindrical symmetry so that we can simplify:
$$\sigma =b\oint \frac{d\Omega}{\sin\theta}\left|\frac{d b}{d\theta}\right|=2\pi b\int_0^\pi d\theta\left|\frac{d b}{d\theta}\right| $$ Here, $b$ is the impact parameter. The absolute value signs are there to assure that we get a positive outcome, even though one usually has lower deflection with larger impact parameters. You may also benefit from reading [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_cross-section), although it will not tell you what to do in your specific situation .